# When I copy table info from web to Excel, all horizontal data go to column A. How to solve it?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2013, website

For example, I try to copy the flight shedule from the airport website below:

https://www.airport.kr/ap/en/arr/arrCargoSchList.do

I copy from the column "airport time" to "arrival status". But all the infomation paste vertically to column A1,A2,A3...etc. ([like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j3qzV.jpg))

And it is hard to use Transpose when I want to copy the whole schedule table.

How do I solve this issue?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Before you paste the data, highlight the number of columns required. Once these blank columns are selected, then paste your data.

Comment: Hi, I tried to highlight 6 columns (from A to F, cus the table has 6 columns), and paste the data. But it poped up a warning "The data you're pasting isn't the same size as your selection. Do you want to paste anyway?". When I clicked OK, they are still all pasted at column A vertically.

Answer (score 0):

If you paste the information to Notepad you will observe that it simply **is** in one column. Sorry, that's how that webpage was set up. However notice that even lines that have empty fields still are symmetrical - that is, whether arrival status is entered or not, you still get exactly 10 excel rows created from each line.

That's good, because you can write a general parsing routine. If you paste your data on Sheet1, Sheet2 can have
b2=Sheet1!A8
c2=Sheet1!A13
etc.
and then copy row 2 down as far as you want, and sheet 2 will show the relevant data correctly.